# How to create a third-party app with node js to apply SSO to Google, Youtube, and Facebook

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid, saml-2.0

I want to create a third-party app that allows my users to login with username and password then applying SSO to other applications? however, I do not want to use Okta or Auth0 because it is too expensive.

I know it is possible due to the fact that it is already done by Auth0 and the others but how to do it manually with a node app for example. More clearly, what are the methods that I need to follow and how?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. Therefore, in the link below that guy has OpenID connect client and provider projects built with Nodejs. The Idp project allows you to have an identity provider and configure any client that supports OpenID connect to your provider.

https://github.com/panva